# How to compute inverse of sum of a unitary matrix and a full rank diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

$C = A+D$, $A$ being a unitary matrix and $D$ a full rank diagonal matrix. Is there any easy way to compute $C^{-1}$ from $A^{-1}$ and $D$, if it exists?

I am interested in this question, because my matrix $A$ is huge and so is $C$. So computing inverse of $C$ from scratch is not practical, but luckily the matrix $A$ is unitary, so $A^{-1} = A^*$, so I easily have $A^{-1}$, and hence finding ways to use it to get $C^{-1}$.

Comment: Is $A$ sparse?  And why do you need the inverse?  If you can avoid explicitly computing $C^{-1}$, you should.

Answer (score 0):

With additional assumptions you can get an infinite series expansion, using the fact that
$$
(I+B)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k B^k
$$
whenever $B$ is a square matrix with spectral radius $\rho(B) < 1$. So
$$
(A+D)^{-1} = (A(I+A^* D))^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (A^* D)^k A^*
$$
if $\rho(A^* D) < 1$, and
$$
(A+D)^{-1} = (D(I+D^{-1}A))^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (D^{-1}A)^k D^{-1}
$$
if $\rho(D^{-1} A) < 1$.

In particular, the first expansion works whenever the entries of $D$ all have absolute values smaller than 1, and the second expansion works whenever the entries of $D$ all have absolute values larger than 1.

Comment: But the matrix multiplications needed to compute a lot of terms of this series may be more time-consuming than matrix inversion.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: True. To make this practically useful you would want to truncate the series after a small number of terms.  If one of the spectral radii is *very* small you could justify that.

Comment: Also, this may be more time-consuming than matrix inversion, but potentially more numerically stable.

Comment: Note that computing *two* (unstructured) matrix products is already more expensive than one matrix inversion.

Comment: Why not to use Cayley Hamilton Theorem?. You should need matrix powers and sums just up to n terms independent of spectral radious. I think this is one of the fastest way to compute such inverse,